# Drawable folder for 4:3 devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, tablet

I'm developing a game for tablet devices. Currently I'm using drawable-sw600dp and drawable-sw720dp folders to place graphics for 7 and 10 inch devices respectively. But the problem is that the graphics are made according to traditional 16:10 devices which do not scale well on 4:3 devices like nexus 9. I've tried using drawable-sw720dp-notlong, drawable-2048x1536 and a number of different qualifier. Nothing works.  If anyone could tell me what folder will work for 4:3 devices without affecting other devices that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> values-sw720dp-notlong

worked very well for me on Nexus-9 (you have typo in word "**notlong**"), it was prioritized before

> values-sw720dp

If it still doesn't work, please check if you don't have other qualifiers with higher priority.

Configuration qualifiers, in order of precedence:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2

Comment: When I use notlong other sw720dp devices like nexus 10 start picking drawables from it too.

Comment: @Talha Mir according to [Android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch), `notlong` modifier should be eliminated on long devices. You may also try transfer aspect-ratio-depending drawables from `drawable-sw720dp` to `drawable-sw720dp-long`